# LeetCode 1: How to translate the question two sum from ReasonML to Clojure?

Tags: algorithm, clojure, functional-programming, reason

I did the question "[**TwoSum**](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/)"  in ReasonML/Ocaml but I have no idea how to code that in Clojure with similar pseudo algorithm. Please comment how to translate this solution to Clojure

**Clojure**

```
(def nums [2 7 11 15])
(def target 9)

(defn two-sum [n xs]
  (let [ixs (map vector xs (range (count xs)))]))
```

**ReasonML**

```
  module TwoSum: {
    let twoSum: (int, Belt.List.t(int)) => list(list(int));
    let run: unit => unit;
  } = {

    let logl = l => l |> Array.of_list |> Js.log;

    let concatmap = (xs: list('a), f) => {
      List.concat(List.map(x => f(x), xs));
    };

    let twoSum = (n, xs) => {
      let ixs = Belt.List.zip([0, ...range(1, List.length(xs))], xs);
      concatmap(ixs, ((i, x)) =>
        concatmap(drop(i, ixs), ((j, y)) => x + y == n ? [[i, j]] : [])
      );
    };

    let run = () => {
      Printf.printf("1. Two Sum :\n");
      let res = twoSum(21, [0, 2, 11, 19, 90, 10]);
      res |> logl;

    };
  };
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the "TwoSum question" you are referring
too

Comment: @cfrick Please refer this link "https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/"

Answer (score 3):

You can use [for](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) to list all the possible index pairs and the `:when` option to filter pairs that fulfill the two-sum conditions. This will return a sequence of possible solutions. Then you pick the first solution.

```
(defn two-sum [numbers target]
  (let [inds (range (count numbers))]
    (first (for [i inds
                 j inds
                 :when (and (not= i j)
                            (= target (+ (nth numbers i)
                                         (nth numbers j)))) ]
             [i j]))))

(two-sum [2 7 11 15] 9)
;; => [0 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

As a slight variation, I would use a helper function [indexed](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.212/api/tupelo.core#indexed) to convert `[:a :b :c]` into:

```
[[0 :a]
 [1 :b]
 [2 :c]]
```

then we get:

```
(defn indexed
  [vals]
  (mapv vector (range) vals))

(defn two-sum
  [vals tgt]
  (let [idx-vals (indexed vals)]
    (first
      (for [[i x] idx-vals  ; destructure each pair => local vars i & x
            [j y] idx-vals
            :when (and (< i j)
                    (= tgt (+ x y)))]
        [i j]))))
```

and results

```
(two-sum [2 7 11 15] 666)     => nil
(two-sum [2 7 11 15] 9)       => [0 1]
(two-sum [0 1 2 7 11 15] 9)   => [2 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

i would go with more functional style:

starting from creating `pairs` function:

```
(defn pairs [data]
  (->> data
       (iterate rest)
       (take-while seq)
       (mapcat (fn [[x & xs]] (map (partial vector x) xs)))))

user> (pairs [:a :b :c :d])
;;=> ([:a :b] [:a :c] [:a :d] [:b :c] [:b :d] [:c :d])
```

then you can generate those pairs of index-to-item tuples:

```
user> (pairs (map-indexed vector [:a :b :c]))
;;=> ([[0 :a] [1 :b]] 
;;    [[0 :a] [2 :c]] 
;;    [[1 :b] [2 :c]])
```

so that you just need to keep the pairs you need:

```
(defn sum2 [target data]
  (->> data
       (map-indexed vector)
       pairs
       (keep (fn [[[i x] [j y]]]
               (when (== target (+ x y))
                 [i j])))))

user> (sum2 9 [2 7 11 15])
;;=> ([0 1])
```

another option is to use list comprehensions for that:

```
(defn sum2 [target data]
  (for [[[i x] & xs] (->> data
                          (map-indexed vector)
                          (iterate rest)
                          (take-while seq))
        [j y] xs
        :when (== target (+ x y))]
    [i j]))

user> (sum2 9 [2 7 11 15])
;;=> ([0 1])
```